# Make Excel 2007 pivot tables default to Classic View

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, formatting, pivot-table

When I launch a new pivot table in Excel 2007 (.xlsx file format) the defaults appear to be:

- New view (not Classic view)
- Autofit column widths on update = on
- Subtotals = on (top of group)

I end up changing these 95 % of the time so would like all newly created pivot tables to have different default settingss - is that possible for any of these?

*(NB: when inserting a new Pivot table in an .xls file format, even in Excel 2007, the Classic view is already default bacause the file format does not support the new style)*